# Solving $2\log_2 (\log_2 x) + \log_{1/2} (\log_2 x) = 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

just looking for some help with the following:

$$2\log_2 (\log_2 x) + \log_{1/2} (\log_2 x) = 1$$

I know how to solve a log equation with a single nested log that's $= 1$ or $0$ or some number, but I'm unsure of what to do when summing/ subtracting nested logs like these.

If possible, a hint would be much more appreciated than the flat out answer.

Thanks in advance to anyone who stops to help.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first perform a change of basis in the second term.

Recall: $\log_{(1/2)}a = \frac{\log_2(a)}{\log_2(1/2)}$

(Of course, then see that $1/2 = 2^{-1}$)

Comment: So, and bare with me, I have to rearrange the second term to be base 2 and then combine that with the first term? Also, how do you write equations on here?

Comment: Other hint: the denominator of the change of basis equals -1. 

(It uses Tex language. See the comment above for useful reference. If you need any other help please ask :) )

Comment: I know I'm probably bothering you, but, I wrote an answer out and was hoping you could check it. (https://prnt.sc/w7rlsc) Sorry about this but I don't have the answer for this booklet. Also, sorry about my handwriting.

Comment: Do not worry, you are here to learn. The result is 4 and not 2. Try again using mu hints and the procedure of the second answer as well.

Comment: Crap, thanks for the help.

Comment: Finally got it after a break, realised that I just squared x instead of the whole log 2 ^ x and the telling me the denominator was -1 got me over the finish line. Thanks again man, really really helped.

Comment: Happy for you! Keep working hard :)

Answer (score 3):

$1)$ Use change of base, to write $$\log_{1/2}(\log_2 x) = - \log_2(\log_2x) $$

$2)$ Let $$\log_2(\log_2 x) = t$$

$3)$ Then $$t= ?$$

$4)$ This means $$\log_2 x =?$$

$5)$ Finally, this means $$x=?$$

$6)$ Check this root in the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's solve a more general problem:

$$\text{n}\log_\alpha\left(\log_\alpha\left(x\right)\right)+\log_\beta\left(\log_\alpha\left(x\right)\right)=\epsilon\tag1$$

First, we know that:

$$\log_\text{a}\left(\text{b}\right):=\frac{\ln\left(\text{b}\right)}{\ln\left(\text{a}\right)}\tag2$$

Let $\text{p}:=\log_\alpha\left(x\right)$, so we get for $(1)$:

$$\text{n}\log_\alpha\left(\text{p}\right)+\log_\beta\left(\text{p}\right)=\epsilon\tag3$$

Using $(2)$ we get:

$$\text{n}\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\text{p}\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(\text{p}\right)}{\ln\left(\beta\right)}=\epsilon\tag4$$

Rewrite the left-hand side, of $(4)$ by combining fractions:

$$\frac{\ln\left(\text{p}\right)\left(\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}=\epsilon\tag5$$

Solving for $\ln\left(\text{p}\right)$, gives:

$$\ln\left(\text{p}\right)=\epsilon\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)}\tag6$$

Cancel logarithms by taking $\exp$ of both sides:

$$\text{p}=\exp\left(\epsilon\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)}\right)\tag7$$

Setting the substitution back and using $(2)$:

$$\log_\alpha\left(x\right)=\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)}=\exp\left(\epsilon\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)}\right)\tag8$$

Solving for $\ln\left(x\right)$, gives:

$$\ln\left(x\right)=\ln\left(\alpha\right)\exp\left(\epsilon\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)}\right)\tag9$$

Cancel logarithms by taking $\exp$ of both sides:

$$x=\exp\left(\ln\left(\alpha\right)\exp\left(\epsilon\cdot\frac{\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)}\right)\right)\tag{10}$$

Using:

$$\ln\left(\text{a}^\text{b}\right)=\text{b}\ln\left(\text{a}\right)\tag{11}$$

We can rewrite $(10)$ as follows:

$$x=\alpha^{\exp\left(\frac{\epsilon\ln\left(\alpha\right)\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\text{n}\ln\left(\beta\right)}\right)}\tag{12}$$

> Using your values, we get:
>
> $$x=4\tag{13}$$

Comment: Thanks, will have at it again tomorrow.

Comment: @Jimbo I hope you liked my answer where I solved your problem in a more general case. If you do, you can accept it using the 'V' sign under the up-/downvote button.

Comment: Very long answer but very nice.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for the compliment.

Comment: @JanEerland your answer is nice and I liked it (also upvoted), but it was not a race on who solved in a more general case, it was about to help him. You definitely did not do, since 1) he was looking for simple hints 2) if he had problems of this type, he will for sure find your answer more complicated than necessary. Moreover, you just want the reputation points of the answer. Please be honest and help others, not for your interest.

Comment: +1 I like this answer very much; in my opinion it is the thinking and strategy that is important, not the answer to the particular problem. This is a very useful answer in the long term especially I would say.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent That is exactly the thinking I had when I was answering this question.

Comment: @JanEerland I agree 100% with you, please continue giving great answers like this one! :)